# Searching for a value in an ordered 2D matrix

Tags: java, for-loop, multidimensional-array, time-complexity

I came up with this solution for a problem where I need to search for a value, target, in a left-to-right ordered matrix. To avoided a nested loop I instead did 2 separate loops, one to find the row to search, the other to find the element in that row. Is this an efficient solution?

```
     public boolean searchMatrix(int[][] matrix, int target) {

int colL = matrix[0].length;
int rowL = matrix.length;
int i;

if(matrix[rowL-1][colL-1] < target || matrix[0][0] > target){
return false;
}

for(i=0; i<rowL; i++) {
if (matrix[i][colL - 1] >= target) {
    break; // if the target is less then the highest value of the row, then it must be in this row
}
}

for (int x = 0; x < colL; x++) {
    if (matrix[i][x] == target) { 
        return true;
    }
}

return false;
```

}

Comment: If the matrix is small enough, it is a good solution, as it has time complexity of O(n). If the matrix is huge, since it is already ordered, you could use binary search, which would give you O(log n), but is more complicated to implement (althoug not *much* more complicated)

Comment: Wouldn't the complexity be O(n+m)? Since the row and column size is different. First we go through all the rows, then we go through all the columns (of that row)?

Comment: Yes you are right, I was assuming an n*n matrix. It is still linear, which is important.

Answer (score 0):

let's discuss in terms of the worst case , suppose that your matrix is of size `5 x 5` then the worst case if your item is at position matrix[4][4].
also you are assuming that the matrix already sorted like it has the shape like the following

```
0  1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8  9
10 11 12 13 14
15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24
```

so , if you are searching for `target = 24` then the number of loops to execute in the first `for loop` is **5** and in the second `for loop` is **5** so total number of loops execution = **5 + 5 = 10** while if you are using nested 2 for loops then it will be **5 * 5 = 25** so yes , you indeed decrease the time of expectation , but it's just in case that the matrix is already sorted , but if the matrix is already sorted , you can preform **binary search** instead of **linear search** which will increase the performance more , read more about binary search from  [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search/).

so the edited version of your code to make it work with binary algorithm is as follows :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      int[][] matrix =
                      {{0,  1,  2,  3 , 4},
                       {5,  6,  7 , 8,  9},
                       {10, 11, 12, 13, 14},
                       {15, 16, 17, 18, 19},
                       {20, 21, 22, 23, 24}};
        System.out.println(searchMatrix(matrix, 25));

    }
    public static boolean searchMatrix(int[][] matrix, int target) {

        int colL = matrix[0].length;
        int rowL = matrix.length;

        if(matrix[rowL-1][colL-1] < target || matrix[0][0] > target){
            return false;
        }

        int low, high, mid;
        // binary search for row
        low = 0;
        high = matrix.length-1;
        mid = (low + high) / 2;
        //(mid != 0) &&(matrix[mid][colL - 1] >= target) && (target > matrix[mid-1][colL - 1])
        while (low <= high){

            if ((mid != 0) && (matrix[mid][colL - 1] >= target) && (target > matrix[mid-1][colL - 1]))
                break;

            if (target > matrix[mid][colL - 1]){
                low = mid + 1;
                mid = (low + high) / 2;
            }
            else if (target < matrix[mid][colL - 1]){
                high = mid - 1;
                mid = (low + high) / 2;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        }

        int rowNum = mid;

        // binary search for column
        low = 0;
        high = matrix[0].length-1;
        mid = (low + high) / 2;
        while (low <= high) {
            if (target > matrix[rowNum][mid]) {
                low = mid + 1;
                mid = (low + high) / 2;
            } else if (target < matrix[rowNum][mid]) {
                high = mid - 1;
                mid = (low + high) / 2;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

the time complexity of nested for loops is **O(n^2)** and time complexity of your code is **O(n+m)** which can be **O(n)** for simplicity , but time complexity for binary search version is **O(log(n) + log (m))** which can be **O(log(n))** for simplicity because every loop search by looking whether to loop up in the lower or upper half